# Is there a way trigger or to call a jenkins job in a loop (foreach param)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to call a specific job B from a job root A.

The job B have to call the job A foreach value in an array of string.

The number of calling job B by job A depend on the size of the array of string.

Is there a plugin or a way to do that?

Comment: how do you get the string array ?

Comment: I want to call a test job through a list of branch, tag, ...

Comment: did not answer my question.  where does the string array come from ?

Comment: It is given by a user in a paramater